# How do I add time (Hours, Minutes) to a time stamp?

Tags: python, timestamp

This is what I have so far, how would I change to add any hours and minutes input by the user?

```
 from datetime import datetime
 str(datetime.now())[00:00]
 addTime =
```

Comment: pretty much....

Comment: Then I'd recommend you run through a tutorial and the `datetime` documentation.

Comment: @EricJVuong well admitting that is the first step to learning, I suggest you go look up the python `slice` notation or `datetime` methods and come back when you managed to get the current time in hours or minutes, making a good attempt before asking for help is more likely to get your question answered on StackOverflow rather than being downvoted

Answer (score 2):

You can just use the addition operator `+` to add two timestamps, so to add 10 minutes to the current time and store it in a variable named `addTime` your code would look like this:

```
import datetime
addTime = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=10)
```